# Open new Form Window in C# .net

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have two forms in Visual Studio for C# .net. One is **Form1** another is **LoginForm**. When I start the project, **Form1** is opened. I have a **button** in **Form1** which when clicked should open **LoginForm**. How do i do this.

Comment: This such question has been asked so many times previously. Did you try a web search prior to posting?

Comment: @Veleous Ya now the problem look the same.But this answer now clears my doubt.Other question was not understandable to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In design view of **Form1**, double click on your **button**. You will be taken to a method. Add the following lines:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new LoginForm().Show();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    LoginForm login=new LoginForm();
    login.ShowDialog();
}
```